# How do I use this function to change the value of t in Python?

Tags: python, function, math, neural-network

I'm learning how to create a basic neural network from scratch in Python. I want to create a function that takes in the parameter, and then change the value of the parameter to the output of the mathematical function I'm using. This will probably make more sense when I show the code.

```
def squash(t):
    t = 1 / (1 + math.pow(math.e, t * -1))
    return
```

I want whatever parameter I put in `t` to have its value changed to the output of the function, but when I call the function in my code, no change is made to the parameter. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about mutable/immutable types in python. And also scopes of variables.

Coming towards a solution, you probably want

```
def squash(t):
    t = 1 / (1 + math.pow(math.e, t * -1))
    return t

my_var = squash(my_var)
```

Comment: Immutability isn't really the concern here. The behavior would be the same for a mutable object like a list. This is a question of reassigning vs mutating, not immutability vs mutability.

Comment: Funny how one simple character can solve the problem. Thank you!

Comment: I am sorry, i am afraid you are wrong about the behavior. If you pass a list/dict and change it in the function, the original list changes

Comment: Nope. [This code](https://gist.github.com/carcigenicate/b6252baed4452acebbf89eb964a2bffe) prints `[1, 2, 3]`. For it to effect the list, you would need to directly mutate the list by calling a method on it or something similar to change its state. Reassigning has no effect.